# R. How to add sum row in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I know this question is very elementary, but I'm having a trouble adding an extra row to show summary of the row.

Let's say I'm creating a data.frame using the code below:

```
name <- c("James","Kyle","Chris","Mike")
nationality <- c("American","British","American","Japanese")
income <- c(5000,4000,4500,3000)
x <- data.frame(name,nationality,income)
```

The code above creates the data.frame below:

```
  name nationality income
1 James    American  5000
2  Kyle     British  4000
3 Chris    American  4500
4  Mike    Japanese  3000
```

What I'm trying to do is to add **a 5th row** and contains: **name = "total", nationality = "NA", age = total of all rows.** My desired output looks like this:

```
  name nationality  income
1 James    American  5000
2 Kyle     British   4000
3 Chris    American  4500
4 Mike    Japanese   3000
5 Total      NA      16500
```

In a real case, my data.frame has more than a thousand rows, and I need efficient way to add the total row.

Can some one please advice? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rbind`

```
 rbind(x, data.frame(name='Total', nationality=NA, income = sum(x$income)))
 #    name nationality income
 #1 James    American   5000
 #2  Kyle     British   4000
 #3 Chris    American   4500
 #4  Mike    Japanese   3000
 #5 Total        <NA>  16500
```

Answer (score 1):

using index.

```
name <- c("James","Kyle","Chris","Mike")
nationality <- c("American","British","American","Japanese")
income <- c(5000,4000,4500,3000)
x <- data.frame(name,nationality,income, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

x[nrow(x)+1, ] <- c('Total', NA, sum(x$income))
```

**UPDATE: using `list`**

```
x[nrow(x)+1, ] <- list('Total', NA, sum(x$income))
x
#    name nationality income
# 1 James    American   5000
# 2  Kyle     British   4000
# 3 Chris    American   4500
# 4  Mike    Japanese   3000
# 5 Total        <NA>  16500
sapply(x, class)
#        name nationality      income 
# "character" "character"   "numeric"
```

Comment: All numerics are turned into characters.

Comment: Please see my UPDATE. @Pascal

Answer (score -4):

If you want the exact row as you put in your post, then the following should work:

```
newdata = rbind(x, data.frame(name='Total', nationality='NA', income = sum(x$income)))
```

I though agree with Jaap that you may not want this row to add to the end. In case you need to load the data and use it for other analysis, this will add to unnecessary trouble. However, you may also use the following code to remove the added row before other analysis:

```
newdata = newdata[-newdata$name=='Total',]
```

Comment: In what this answer is different from Akrun's one? (I add this comment again, as it seems it has been deliberately deleted).